# Preenchendo Label com Linq usando ToList()?

Tags: c#, foreach, linq-to-sql

Tenho uma tabela com o seguinte esquemas:

```
GarantiaImovel | imovelID | GarantiasTipos
12             |    3     | Caução2
12             |    4     | Depósito
12             |    5     | Caução2
12             |    5     | Fiador
12             |    5     | Seguro Fiança
```

Então tenho a seguinte `Query`:

```
var garantias = (from p in db.T_GarantiasLocaticias
                         where p.imovelID == 5
                         select p.GarantiasTipos).ToList();
```

A minha intenção nesta `Query` é retornar as três linhas na tabela acima com a coluna `GaantiasTipo`, mas eu usando o `foreach` e ele só me retorna a ultima linha como posso retornar na seguinte estrutura:

```
foreach (var garantia in garantias)
{
     lblGarantiaLocaticias.Text = garantia + ", ";
}
```

Como proceder?

Comment: Era só usar um **`+=`**. Assim: `lblGarantiaLocaticias.Text += garantia + ", ";`. O `foreach` vai ser produzido de qualquer maneira, seja explicitamente ou no `string.Join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não precisa fazer um [foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) é só usar [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) com o retorno daquele expressão [linq](/questions/tagged/linq), ***exemplo***:

```
var garantias = (from p in db.T_GarantiasLocaticias
                  where p.imovelID == 5
                  select p.GarantiasTipos)
               .ToList();

lblGarantiaLocaticias.Text = String.Join(", ", garantias);
```

[Exemplo Online](https://repl.it/KL2N/1)

***Observação:*** até pode utilizar um `for` ou `foreach` ou até um `while`, mas, não há necessidade já visto que [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) já faz isso de forma ***transparente***. Uma outra *observação* é sobre o que estava acontecendo, porque faltou acumular os valores já obtidos nas interações e que no `foreach` da sua pergunta não fazia, no caso seria só colocar um sinal de mais (**+**) antes do igual (**=**) ([que representa um operador de atribuição de adição](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator))  e um ajuste para que no último elemento não tivesse a virgula (**,**) ***desta forma***:

```
lblGarantiaLocaticias.Text = "";
foreach (var garantia in garantias)
{
     if (lblGarantiaLocaticias.Text != "") 
         lblGarantiaLocaticias.Text += ", ";
     lblGarantiaLocaticias.Text += garantia;
}
```

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método String.Join(String, IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método String.Join (String, String[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [dotnetperls - string-join](https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join)
- [Operador += (Referência de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator)

Comment: Exatamente isso!
Eu de tanto olhar outros recursos não atentei para o String.Join

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o [`Aggregate(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) (vulgo *reduce*):

```
var garantias = (from p in db.T_GarantiasLocaticias
                 where p.imovelID == 5
                 select p.GarantiasTipos)
                .ToList()
                .Aggregate(string.Empty, (actual, novo) => 
                {
                    // caso a string concatenada nao esteja vazia,
                    // adiciona o separador
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actual)) {
                        actual += ","
                    }

                    return actual + novo;
                });
```

Pode ver um exemplo do `Aggregate` [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WVxso4).

Comment: Vendo assim, parece que seria um boa opção, mas, além dos erros de codificação e falta de codificação ele acaba fazendo da mesma forma que o meu fez na primeira solução, portanto, `"Se não quiser percorrer a colecção duas vezes, pode usar"` não é um argumento válido.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic depende, se o OP usar os objectos trazidos para mais alguma coisa, não há nada de errado em usar o string.Join. Caso queira apenas construir a string, evita materializar a colecçao com o ToList e depois percorrer a mesma novamente com o string.Join(....). Mesmo que nao considere o argumento válido, o Aggregate continua a ser uma alternativa viável. E obrigado por indicar os erros ;)

Comment: O Aggregate só vai funcionar depois da materialização da camada ORM (ou seja, no Linq para Objetos) utilizada, ou seja, vai dar na mesma, não disse que essa solução não é viável ele é viável sim, só disse que o argumento utilizado não confere para utilizar a solução.